# how to deselect all nodes in JSTree

Tags: jquery, jstree, jstree-search

I am building JS tree dynamically.

I am deleting node and when it happens,it is selecting to the above node and "select_node" event is getting triggered.

I want to override the default functionality

```
 $('#treeViewContainer').css("height", 100px);
  treeView = $('#treeView1');
  treeView.bind('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
   }
```

I tried to deselect all immediately after deleting the node,but  'select_node' event is getting triggered.

```
 if ($('#treeViewResults').length != 0)
 {
     treeView.jstree("delete_node", $('#treeViewResults'));
     $('#treeView1').jstree("deselect_all");
  }
```

How to skip 'select_node' event from getting triggered or deselect all nodes 
immediately after deleting the node before triggering the 'select_node' event.

Please suggest

Answer (score 8):

I am also using jsTree to show folder structure. When user select item in jsTree then a new tab will open in the tab host like visual studio code. Then I need to highlight the jsTree item when user selects a tab again like visual studio code.
So have 2 scenarios to complete this functionality

1 - deselect all nodes manually

```
$("#jsTree").jstree().deselect_all(true);
```

2 - select the appropriate item manually

```
$("#jsTree").jstree().select_node('item id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set'select_prev_on_delete' property to false which is by default to true.and it solved the problem.

```
 $('#treeViewContainer').css("height", 100px);
  treeView = $('#treeView1');
  treeView.bind('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
   })
 .jstree({
            'json_data': {
                "data": treeData
            },
            'ui': {
                "select_limit": 1,
                "select_prev_on_delete": false
            },
```